Grouping multiple traces in OpenTelemetry
I have a request 'Get a list of books', the request contains a uniqueId, the API creates a new Trace using StartActivity.
I have another request 'Buy book', the request contains the same uniqueId as 'Get a list of books', the API creates a new Trace using StartActivity.
In my observability tool (DataDog) I see the two traces but I would like to see a single view so I can see the trace from 'Get a list of books' through to the 'Buy book' request. This will allow me to see the whole user journey.
How would I achieve this using OpenTelemetry? The API is stateless, the only thing that the requests have in common is the uniqueId.

First of, a quick comment on this:

...the API creates a new Trace using StartActivity.

From how you put it, it appears you are doing this manually, by yourself, in code? If so, I'd strongly suggest you stop doing that and switch into using OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.AspNetCore package and the automatic AspNetCore instrumentation there. That will ensure every request to your API creates a trace using all OTEL-defined best practices/spec.
Now, regarding your ask to "group" the calls together by this uniqueId value, my suggestion would be as follows. I assume that, if you have this uniqueId across calls, that it is kept somewhere, perhaps on a frontend SPA application (if you could add more detail on your API consumer that would be great).
If so, the best course of action to see a "full flow" in your case would be to actually add OpenTelemetry instrumentation to your clientside. This way, the client will have a root trace created for it, that will then naturally contain all calls it makes to the API to "perform its work". You should then see the 2 traces, one for Get a list of books and another for Buy book as part of that same trace (assuming both operations are performed in the same context).
OpenTelemetry takes care of propagating the autogenerated traceId value across application boundaries, and that is the value that is then used to correlate all the various distributed spans into a single cohesive trace. In the case of the AspNetCore instrumentation, for example, if you make a call to the API from a non-instrumented context, the API span will become the root span, otherwise the API span will become a child of the span passed via trace context. This all happens transparently.
